# How to space tables in sqlite?

Tags: linux, sqlite

I am running Linux and have written code to create and open a database in sqlite3. The code then creates a few dummy tables with a few dummy entries. Once that is complete I run

```
sqlite3 test.db < ./sqliteauto.sql
```

My sqliteauto.sql code is as follows:

```
--general settings
.headers on
.mode columns

--people table
.width 3 6 4
select * from PEOPLE; 

--state table
.width 3 11 5
select * from STATES;
.quit
```

This returns my two dummy tables and values with the correct spacing and column width I have coded in sqliteauto.sql. The only problem is that the last entry of the table flows into the the column headers of the next table.

It looks like this:

```
ID1     NAME     AGE
-----   ------   ----
1       Steve    25
2       Chris    30
ID2     STATE    ABRV
-----   ------   -----
1       Texas    TX
2       Georgia  GA
```

What do I put in my sqliteauto.sql code to insert a new line between tables to make it display better in the command prompt like this:

```
ID1     NAME     AGE
-----   ------   ----
1       Steve    25
2       Chris    30


ID2     STATE    ABRV
-----   ------   -----
1       Texas    TX
2       Georgia  GA
```

Comment: I assume that your sqliteauto.sql file finishes with 2 select statements. If your statements are running from one to another without terminating in between you may see the response you are getting. Post the select / output part of your file to enable us to help you (or maybe even your build script so as we can do the whole testing thing).

Comment: I have added my sqliteauto.sql code

Comment: Having had a look at this page http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html I feel that you should be output a line break wherever you like in your output...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the `sqlite3` tool output an empty line, use the command `.print ''`.

Comment: .print returns "Error: unknown command or invalid arguments:  "print". Enter ".help" for help"

Comment: No parameters work in version 3.7.17; an empty parameter should also work in earlier versions.

Comment: *SOLVED* Does not work with version 3.6.22 not sure about the last number (22). Just spent an hour and a half upgrading to the newest version. Linux is too confusing. Thanks for the answer. I now have the newest version working and outputting perfect data with .print!

Comment: Sorry I can't give an upvote yet but this did work for me. Also with a quick search on the version history at http://www.sqlite.org/changes.html the .print was not implemented until 3.7.15. Running 3.7.17 all is happy now.

Answer (score 0):

OK after much hunting on the SQLite page, I found this..

http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/mprintf.html

> For example, assume the string variable zText contains text as
>   follows:
>
> char *zText = "It's a happy day!"; One can use this text in an SQL
>   statement as follows:
>
> char *zSQL = sqlite3_mprintf("INSERT INTO table VALUES('%q')", zText);
>   sqlite3_exec(db, zSQL, 0, 0, 0); sqlite3_free(zSQL);

The question is how to implement it? I assume you are running your script from an external file.

As the docs say that mprintf is like the C printf you should be able to use it to directly print to the output.

try something like

```
sqlite3_mprintf("___    ____")
```

Of course I may be wrong, you'll have to try it out...

David

Comment: Thanks for hunting around for this. I haven't tried to implement it because as I was awaiting a response I upgraded to the latest version of sqlite3. CL's response now works perfectly but I don't have enough reputation to give him an upvote =/